# MIFA Antenna Design for BLE in KiCad?

Tags: antenna, kicad

I am looking to design an Antenna (MIFA) for BLE (2.4GHz) in Kicad. But I can't find it in libraries. Even we can't design footprint of custom shape with Kicad Footprint editor. Can somebody help me in designing antenna?

**EDIT:**

My question is about designing a custom shape in kicad so that I can design `MIFA` antenna of required shape and size. The question is not about `How to design MIFA antenna for BLE`. I can't find anything in `Kicad` to design a pad of custom shape.

Comment: [Maybe this will help.  These folks built a 2.4GHz bluetooth antenna using Kicad.](https://www.seenov.com/kicad-2-4ghz-antenna-design/).

Comment: This is too broad. Make an attempt, then we have something to discuss: either your design or the obstacles you've met underway. Vtc.

Comment: The question is how to design the shape of antenna in kiCad. Kicada doesn't have tool to design custom shapes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about this, none are pretty.

1. MIFA antenna shape can be broken down into simple rectangles, in the footprint editor, you can add pads of the required size and calculate its position, you will need to calculate lot of offsets as the pad location is referenced to its center and I assume the MIFA antenna shape will have dimensions between edges.
2. Using inkscape. Create a shape in inkscape and export it to png. convert it to binary image using GIMP or similar tools, next use Bitmap2Component, open image file by clicking on Load bitmap set the resolution so the image is not scaled. Set the "Format" to Pbcnew(.kicad_mod) and "Board layer" to Front silk screen. Hit export.
   This will generate component file with silkscreen of the custom shape. Now open the component file in a text editor and replace F.Silk with F.Cu.
   Now open this file in footprint editor and check if the custom shape is on F.Cu Layer. Now add a pad and place it inside the custom shape, nearest to where the wire would connect. Save it and that is it.
   (I recommend starting with a square shape and then start with the antenna design after you have got the process).

Sadly, there is no other way around it as far as i know.